# Adding a formula to an existing code in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim NextRow As Long

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
NextRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

MsgBox NextRow

With sht
    With .Range("B" & NextRow & ":B" & NextRow + 4)
      .merge
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With .Range("J" & NextRow & ":J" & NextRow + 4)
      .merge
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With .Range("K" & NextRow & ":K" & NextRow + 4)
      .merge
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With .Range("L" & NextRow & ":L" & NextRow + 4)
      .merge
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With .Range("C" & NextRow & ":C" & NextRow + 4)
      .merge
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    With .Range("F" & NextRow & ":F" & NextRow + 4)
      .merge
      .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
   End With

   .Range("A" & NextRow & ":A" & NextRow + 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R5C2:RC[1],RC[1])"

   .Range("B" & NextRow) = TextBox1
   .Range("J" & NextRow) = ComboBox1
   .Range("K" & NextRow) = ComboBox3
   .Range("L" & NextRow) = ComboBox2

   If CheckBox1 = True Then .Range("E" & NextRow) = "URS"
   If CheckBox2 = True Then .Range("E" & NextRow + 1) = "RA"
   If CheckBox3 = True Then .Range("E" & NextRow + 2) = "TM"
   If CheckBox4 = True Then .Range("E" & NextRow + 3) = "IOQ"
   If CheckBox5 = True Then .Range("E" & NextRow + 4) = "FR"

End With

MsgBox "All done"

End Sub
```

It is used to add a new line to my spreadsheet with  the information that is entered into a user form. I have all of this working, but I have two formulas in column C and F that I need to be carried into the new line. I can't simply drag the formulas down the column because there are merged cells in each row that are merged after my code is run. I have tried several different formula functions in my code and all are returning errors. Any ideas as to how I should add these formulas into my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula that you're adding (`"=COUNTIF(R5C2:RC[1],RC[1])"`) throws a circular reference error when you paste it into a workbook cell. The `.Range().FormulaR1C1 = ""` will fail because of the formula error. Adjust the formula and try again.